# How to load two extended JPanel class to one JFrame?

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, paint

I'm going to make a game with Java, my game will have a menu. the menu is having a background, and 2 `JLabel` objects. I've make them on separate class, which is passed to one `JFrame`.  And my problem is, I've load 2 of them on a single frame, but one of them always hidden by another.

this is the code:

### JFrame class

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Sistem extends JFrame{
private final int lebar=954;
private final int tinggi=540;
private Image bg;
File gbr=new File("res/a.jpg");

public Sistem(){
    this.setTitle("Unknown man Unkown power");
    this.setSize(new Dimension(lebar,tinggi));
    this.setFocusable(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setContentPane(new Ngrep());
    //this.setContentPane(new Menu());


    this.setVisible(true);
    //loadfont();
    //loadbg();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new Sistem();
        }
    });
}

}
```

### background class

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Ngrep extends JPanel{
private int l=954;
private int t=540;
private BufferedImage bg;
File gbr=new File("res/a.jpg");

public Ngrep(){
    loadbg();

}

private void loadbg() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        bg=ImageIO.read(gbr);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.paint(g);
    g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, l, t, null);
}

}
```

### menu class

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Menu extends JPanel implements Runnable,KeyListener{
private int l=954;
private int t=540;
JLabel menu1=new JLabel("MULAI BARU");
JLabel menu2=new JLabel("KELUARRR");
private File fo=new File("res/Mawns.ttf");
JLayeredPane p=new JLayeredPane();

public Menu(){
    loadfont();

    this.add(menu1);
    this.add(menu2);
}


public void loadfont(){
    try {
        FileInputStream fi=new FileInputStream(fo);
        Font f=Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, fi).deriveFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, 30);
        GraphicsEnvironment ge=GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();

        ge.registerFont(f);

        menu1.setFont(f);
        menu2.setFont(f);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    p.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 3));

    menu1.setBounds(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    menu2.setBounds(0, 0+menu1.getHeight(), getWidth(), getHeight());

    p.add(menu1, 2);
    p.add(menu2, 2);
}


}
```

What I want is the menu is in front of background but background still can be seen. and how to arrange the `JLabel` that I've created to center down of the screen.

How can I achieve the required layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Ngrep extends JPanel{
```

Note that since `Ngrep` **is a** `JPanel` you can add components directly to it, making the `Menu` class redundant.

Something like seen in this SSCCE.

[image: Sistem preview]

Note that I ended up making so many changes so fast I could not be bothered explicitly documenting most of them.  Look over the code carefully, check it against your original code, check the Java Docs, and if there is any change you do not understand, ask me.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Sistem extends JFrame {

    public Sistem() {
        this.setTitle("Unknown man Unkown power");
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setContentPane(new Ngrep());
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.pack();

        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Sistem();
            }
        });
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class Ngrep extends JPanel {

    private int l = 375;
    private int t = 150;
    private BufferedImage bg;
    JLabel menu1 = new JLabel("MULAI BARU");
    JLabel menu2 = new JLabel("KELUARRR");

    public Ngrep() {
        this.add(menu1);
        this.add(menu2);

        try {
            Font f = new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.ITALIC, 30);
            menu1.setFont(f);
            menu1.setForeground(Color.RED);
            menu2.setFont(f);
            menu2.setForeground(Color.RED);
            URL url = new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVOg3.jpg");
            bg = ImageIO.read(url);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 3));

        add(menu1);
        add(menu2);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(l, t);
    }

    /*
     * For a JComponent, override paintComponent rather than paint
     */
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        // a JPanel IS AN ImageObserver
        g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
    }
}
```

Comment: i've tried it, but still it only shows the BufferedImage. is it ImageIO cant be overlapped?

Comment: I just find my fault, that i use "paint()" instead of "paintComponent()" thank to you,

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Start by using `JFrame#add` instead of `JFrame#setContentPane`, unless you intend to add more components to that (content) pane.

By default `JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout` for its `LayoutManager`. You will need to either change it to something you prefer to use OR add each component to an appropriate position within the `BorderLayout`

See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

Comment: As I said, the default layout manager `JFrame` is a `BorderLayout`.  If you add both components with specifying a location, they will be added to the `CENTER` position, but only the last one will be displayed.  Check the link for more details...

Answer (score 0):

solved, because I've found that i use paint() instead of paintComponent().
like this:

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.paint(g);
g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, l, t, this);
}
```

to this :

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.paintComponents(g);

g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, l, t, this);
}
```